# Printing Text in console from textview

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview

I have a text view in my project, that changes different text when the user does something.  But how can i print the text in the console. So everytime the text changes, it will show in the console as well.

Here is my code for the text view.

```
self.heardTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Heard: \"%@\"", hypothesis]; // Show it in the status box.
```

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", self.heardTextView.text)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can achieve this:

One way is to simply use `NSLog(@" the text is %@", self.heardTextView.text)` statements

You can use the native delegate methods given by the apple:

Implement this to print the message after you made any changes to the textview

```
  - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

        NSLog(@" the text is %@", self.heardTextView.text)

        if([self.heardTextView.text isEqualToString:@"hello"]){
         //do something
        }
  }
```

You can also use KVO to observer whenever there is a chnage in the textView text.

```
heardTextView.text=@"old";
[heardTextView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
heardTextView.text=@"hello";

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    NSLog(@"the text changed");
    NSLog(@"changed text is %@",change[@"new"]);
}
```

Comment: It's a text view, not a label. Use the proper delegate methods. No need for KVO.

Comment: Thanks. It's showing into the console now!   One more question, if wanted to create a 'else if', and when the textfield shows a certain text, it will run some code. How can i do this?

Comment: do u mean text view ? or text field ?

Comment: @Mr.t It's a textview

Comment: Yeah.  It's running in the console all fine and I'm using you're updated code.  But when i try to create a 'else if', when the text field says this run this code... It's not working..